Unable to access the Red Hat DataGrid/Infinispan console on Openshift first installation
Context
I am deploying a microservices application in an Openshift environment controlled by the customer I work for. I have access, not unlimited, to Openshift console in dev environments.
I need to deploy an Infinispan-based cache that Spring Boot will utilize.
For now, the customer's sysadmin has deployed the RH DataGrid Operator 8.4 upon our request. The sysadmin cannot support us in terms of Datagrid configuration. I have been spending some time into the official documentation before coming here.
The problem
After a number of try-and-fails, I deployed a helm template that instantiates the Infinispan cluster as Custom Resource (CR), and opened its route to the external to start playing around. To give you a little more context, I will proceed with my tasks by definfing the kind: Cache objects once I first get some practice with the console and validate the installation. A good chance to learn the tool.
The template so far
---
# Source: ipe-cache/templates/config.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: prj-cache-cm
data:
  infinispan-config.yaml: |-
    infinispan:
      cacheContainer:
        caches:
          base-template:
            distributedCacheConfiguration:
              encoding:
                mediaType: application/x-protostream
              expiration:
                lifespan: "3600"
          extended-template:
            distributedCacheConfiguration:
              configuration: base-template
              expiration:
                lifespan: "36000"
                maxIdle: "1000"
---
# Source: prj-cache/templates/infinispan.yaml
apiVersion: infinispan.org/v1
kind: Infinispan
metadata:
  name: prj-cache-infinispan
spec:
  replicas: 1
  configMapName: prj-cache-cm
  service:
    type: DataGrid
  expose:
    type: Route
    port: 11223
    targetPort: 11223
    tls:
      termination: edge
      insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: Redirect
  logging:
    categories:
      org.infinispan: debug
      org.jgroups: debug
      org.jgroups.protocols.TCP: error
      org.jgroups.protocols.relay.RELAY2: error

After this is deployed, under Operators -> Data Grid -> Infinispan Cluster I can see resource of type Infinispan name ipe-cache-dev-infinispan that is associated
> oc get service -l infinispan_cr=ipe-cache-dev-infinispan
NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan         ClusterIP   192.168.140.225   <none>        11222/TCP   141m
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-admin   ClusterIP   None              <none>        11223/TCP   141m
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-ping    ClusterIP   None              <none>        8888/TCP    141m
> oc get pods -l infinispan_cr=ipe-cache-dev-infinispan
NAME                                                        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-0                                  1/1     Running   0          141m
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-config-listener-74f47669bd-tgxx7   1/1     Running   0          139m
> oc get routes -l infinispan_cr=ipe-cache-dev-infinispan
NAME                                HOST/PORT                                                                              PATH   SERVICES                   PORT    TERMINATION   WILDCARD
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-external   ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-external-e3-ipe-ipe-dev.apps.wepay-noprod.acme.eu          ipe-cache-dev-infinispan   11222   passthrough   None
> oc get configmaps -l infinispan_cr=ipe-cache-dev-infinispan
NAME                                     DATA   AGE
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-configuration   4      141m
> oc get services -l infinispan_cr=ipe-cache-dev-infinispan
NAME                             TYPE        CLUSTER-IP        EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)     AGE
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan         ClusterIP   192.168.140.225   <none>        11222/TCP   141m
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-admin   ClusterIP   None              <none>        11223/TCP   141m
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-ping    ClusterIP   None              <none>        8888/TCP    141m
> oc get secrets -l infinispan_cr=ipe-cache-dev-infinispan
NAME                                                 TYPE     DATA   AGE
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-generated-operator-secret   Opaque   4      141m
ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-infinispan-security         Opaque   2      141

So, I want to connect to the console by using the externally-exposed endpoint at https://ipe-cache-dev-infinispan-external-e3-ipe-ipe-dev.apps.wepay-noprod.acme.eu. The problem is that when I access the console I am requested for the user/password but all are refused.
In order to get the default password, I tried to retrieve the secret from Openshift and base64-decode it (it gets a yaml file with developer user and a random password).
What I tried also
I tried to increase the log verbosity to debug but when I authenticate I can't get anything logged in the pod.
I also tried F12 on the Openshift Console to intercept HTTP request but when I enter username/password no request is apparently sent by the browser. But when I hit cancel, I can see the 401 error, still without logs.
If I login into the CLI from the pod's terminal after revealing the developer password from
sh-4.4$ ./cli.sh 
[disconnected]> connect
http://localhost:11223
Username: developer
Password: ****************
The supplied credentials are invalid

What should I be looking for, in order to log in to the console? Is there any configuration missing here?
